# Evaluate of $\int \frac{(a+bx)^k}{x} dx$

Tags: integration, special-functions

Consider the integral
$$
\int \frac{(a+bx)^k}{x} dx.
$$
Does this have a representation using (preferably) elementary or special functions?

Edit: $0 <k<1$.

Wolfram alpha produces an expression involving the (I did not know about this function beforehand) 2F1 hypergeometric function without explanation.  I guess it can be attained by the integral representation [here](http://functions.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunctions/Hypergeometric2F1/07/ShowAll.html), but I am hoping something simpler might exist - in particular something which is easier to evaluate numerically.

Comment: Does $k\in \mathbb{N}$? If yes, you can develop the expression and integrate.

Comment: @Martigan No, unfortunately not. I will edit adding the asumption on $k$.

Comment: Making the change of variables $a+bx=t$, we arrive at something like $c \int \frac{t^kdt}{1-z t}$. Expanding in powers of $z$ and integrating, one gets non-simplifiable hypergeometric series.